# Using rotated projection in NetCDF file?

Tags: coordinate-system, netcdf

Could anyone show me a working example of a NetCDF file header with a rotated Cartesian projection where the datum is WGS84?

From [Spatial reference for netCDF data](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/netcdf/spatial-reference-for-netcdf-data.htm)  I see that coordinates can be called  projection_x_coordinate and projection_x_coordinate but it doesn't specify how to fill in the projection type.

Looking at [CF Standard Name Table](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-standard-names/66/build/cf-standard-name-table.html) I see variables such as "angle_of_rotation_from_east_to_x" but I don't know the full set necessary to define a rotated projection.